# Does an equivalent to prepend method exist in ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby

I need to use the [`prepend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) method, introduced in ruby 2.0, in ruby 1.9.3, where this method is not supported. Is there an equivalent method in ruby 1.9.3?

**UPDATE**

I need this working with ruby 1.9.3

```
module ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::BaseExtension
  def add_classes_to_body
    super
    @body.set_attribute "ng-app", "MyApp" #I need to add this line
  end
end
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base
  prepend ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::BaseExtension
end
```

Comment: What problem do you want do solve using `Module#preapend`? To check what other options you can have.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. If there were an equivalent to `prepend` prior to Ruby 2.0, then why would Ruby 2.0 have introduced `prepend`?

Comment: I've updated my question. I did not write the code before trying to make a more general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepend` changes the core Ruby object model, specifically the way messages are dispatched, there is no way to do this in pure Ruby, therefore, there is no way to backport the `prepend` functionality.

In the bad old days before `prepend` we used to do this instead:

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base
  orig = instance_method(:add_classes_to_body)

  define_method(:add_classes_to_body) do
    orig.bind(self).()
    @body.set_attribute "ng-app", "MyApp"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work using [alias_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Module/alias_method)

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base
  alias_method :old_add_classes_to_body, :add_classes_to_body

  def add_classes_to_body
    old_add_classes_to_body
    @body.set_attribute "ng-app", "MyApp"
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have ActiveSupport available, you could use `alias_method_chain` instead. However, both doing it manually or with the help of `alias_method_chain` will pollute the namespace with unnecessary `old_XYZ` methods. Also, you can still call the `old_XYZ` methods, but presumably you want to overwrite them because they are not doing their job properly, so is it really a good idea to still be able to call them?